# Error in Travis trying to submit app to Google's Play Store

Tags: google-api, android-gradle-plugin, google-api-java-client, travis-ci, google-play

I started by looking into a couple of Gists I found on Github: https://gist.github.com/lpetre/87a5196d14cf4484f1f2

And this works great on my laptop, however I'm trying to set up Travis-CI to automatically build the release APK and submit it to the Play Store.  The issue that I'm encountering now is on the Travis side, in that I cannot use pip to install the google_api_python_client.

upon that call, I get the following:

```
 Installing collected packages: google-api-python-client, httplib2
  Running setup.py install for google-api-python-client
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_travis/google-api-python-client/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ctZKCR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

So I strayed away from using pip, downloaded the python client libraries on their own, and am now including them in my git repo (under /google_api_upload).

A part of Google's API Upload client library instructions (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v2/python/README.md) say to run "import apiclient" in a python console (again, works fine on my laptop, but not travis because I can't start a python session and enter in "import apiclient" so far as I've found; it just hangs on the python session).

So then I figured it'd be awesome to just have a Gradle function in my gradle files which calls the API functions, and is called from the travis.yml file; but I don't even know if that's possible.

So any input would help, notably:

- Did I mess up in my attempt at running pip on travis? Can I sudo to elevate permissions for this (I imagine I can't)
- Is there a way to call "import apiclient" for python within a single line in the travis.yml file?
- Is it possible to have travis call a gradle function which refers to client libraries included in my build?
- I've tried to find examples of this end-to-end process, but haven't found any that fit this exact case, do you know of any?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever come to a resolution with all of this?  I'm facing similar issues.

Comment: I got a message back from Travis' support, will add an answer below

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error message

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient': Permission denied
```

and fixed that by adding `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install google-api-python-client
```

Compare build [#162](https://travis-ci.org/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/builds/41866376) and [#163](https://travis-ci.org/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/builds/41866539).

Comment: Where are you safely storing your passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from Travis support, but have not confirmed yet.

> I believe this is an issue reported in
>   https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2280.
>   https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2280#issuecomment-42798869
>   suggests that adding "mvn -pl extras/google-play-services install"
>   should do the trick.

Comment: If you answer your own question, mark it as correct.