# What is the best practice to use keystores to sign release version of an Android app on Travis CI?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I've been using Travis CI to build my [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vngrs.android.pomodoro). I am signing it in the debug builds with a `debug.keystore` which I pushed to [public repository](https://github.com/vngrs/PomoPomoAndroid)

But I want to build the release build and upload them to Google Play Store using this [gradle plugin](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher).

This process needs a `keystore` and a `p12` certificate file.

While I can add encrypted environment variables to Travis CI, I don't know the best way to store these files.

**Question 1:** What is the best practice to do this? And can someone provide an open source implementation? (I couldn't find one)

**One possible implementation:** Store a username and password as a environment variable securely. Store the files in a SSL enabled environment and protect them with these username and password with a simple HTTP authentication. Use them to download using `curl` before build process begin.

**Question 2** Does this implementation make sense at all? Is it secure?

**Extra:** These 2 blog posts are great sources related to this but none of them answers this question unfortunately.

http://stablekernel.com/blog/deploying-google-play-continuous-delivery-android-part-4/
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/continuous-delivery-for-android/

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/

Comment: I am really surprised, even with a bounty, no one has *really* attempted to answer.

Comment: @tasomaniac Have you been able to implement this in to your own repo? I have most of it implemented with that plugin here: https://github.com/NonameDev/MathApp/tree/feature/release_updates.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Updated (5/28/15):

I have started to implement my solution here(open source): https://github.com/NonameDev/MathApp

- Use **`System.getenv("TRAVIS")`** to detect your build is running on Travis.
- **`storeFile rootProject.file('release.keystore')`** - keep release key in your own repository - travis will hide the password
- **`storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASS")`** - store environment variable on travis - travis will hide output
- **`keyAlias System.getenv("ALIAS_NAME")`** - store environment variable on travis - travis will hide output
- **`keyPassword System.getenv("ALIAS_PASS")`** - store environment variable on travis - travis will hide output
- **`System.getenv("SERVICE_EMAIL")`** - store environment variable on travis - travis will hide output
- **`rootProject.file('play.p12')`** - store cert locally - travis will store the email service account

#### Top `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

#### App `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'burrows.apps.mathapp'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        if (System.getenv("TRAVIS")) {
            release {
                storeFile rootProject.file('release.keystore')
                storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASS")
                keyAlias System.getenv("ALIAS_NAME")
                keyPassword System.getenv("ALIAS_PASS")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

if (System.getenv("TRAVIS")) {
    play {
        serviceAccountEmail = System.getenv("SERVICE_EMAIL")
        pk12File = rootProject.file('play.p12')
        track = 'production' // or 'alpha' or 'beta' or 'production'
    }
}
```

### Original Answer:

Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089032/950427)? He posts a link to his TravisCI builds "before" and "after" correcting his build.

Here is his answer:

> Compare build
>   [#162](https://travis-ci.org/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/builds/41866376)
>   and
>   [#163](https://travis-ci.org/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/builds/41866539).

Basically he had to run `sudo pip install google-api-python-client`

With that being said, I checked out the github repo [here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient).

### Here is the his `.travis.yml`:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-21.1.2
    - extra-android-m2repository

env:
  global:
    - secure: <removed>
    - secure: <removed>
before_install:
  - ci/decrypt_files
  - ci/start_emulator

install:
  - ./gradlew build

before_script:
  - ci/wait_for_emulator

script:
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTestMockDebug

after_success:
  - ci/deploy_all

notifications:
  email:
    - <removed>
```

**Source:** https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/.travis.yml

### Before build:

This is the `secure` part of the process where the keys are used and the password is used from TravisCI(securely stored on TravisCI).

```
before_install:
  - ci/decrypt_files
  - ci/start_emulator
```

**Source of `ci/decrypt_files`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -k "$file_password" -in app/gradle.properties.enc -out app/gradle.properties
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -k "$file_password" -in app/crashlytics.properties.enc -out app/crashlytics.properties
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -k "$file_password" -in ci/vielengames.keystore.enc -out ci/vielengames.keystore
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -k "$file_password" -in ci/key.p12.enc -out key.p12
```

**Source:** https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/ci/decrypt_files

### After Build:

This is where `python` and other `Google` libs are being downloaded and used to deploy the app to `Google Play`.

```
after_success:
  - ci/deploy_all
```

**Source of `ci/deploy_all`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
test "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" && ci/deploy_google_play
ci/deploy_testfairy
ci/deploy_crashlytics_beta
```

**Source of `ci/deploy_google_play`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$(dirname $0)

sudo apt-get install python-openssl
sudo pip install google-api-python-client

python $DIR/basic_upload_apks.py com.vielengames $DIR/../app/build/outputs/apk/app-production-release.apk
python $DIR/basic_upload_apks.py com.vielengames.staging $DIR/../app/build/outputs/apk/app-staging-release.apk
```

### Security:

**Your Question 1:**

I believe you have to have have both the `keystore` and `p12` for the app, but you can *safely* store your password with TravisCI(see the `"$file_password"`), just like the example above.

**Your Question 2:**

Even if you have the `keystore` and `p12` cert, you still need the password(see the `"$file_password"`) for both to work and be used to publish to the store.

For extra security, you want to add another login with *less* permissions than you main login. Here is what the author of the repo did [here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/ci/basic_upload_apks.py):

```
...

TRACK = 'beta'  # Can be 'alpha', beta', 'production' or 'rollout'

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = (
    '148768954062-sp89pjb1blr7cu2f73f4fpd6dqloc047@developer.gserviceaccount.com')

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('package_name',
                       help='The package name. Example: com.android.sample')
argparser.add_argument('apk_file',
                       nargs='?',
                       default='test.apk',
                       help='The path to the APK file to upload.')

...
```

**Source:** https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/ci/basic_upload_apks.py

Comment: how to run the publish task, as part of the travis build? this isn't working...script:
  - "./gradlew -i -S clean :app:assembleDebug :app:publishApkXXXXXRelease"

Comment: in the travis build, I keep getting errors like...Task with path 'publishApkRelease' not found in project ':app' or simply, Task 'publishApkRelease' not found.

Comment: I've mimicked your Task and put it in my project's build.gradle...task publish(dependsOn: ['publishApkAPPNAMERelease']) {'
        description = 'Publish to Google Play'
    }

Comment: on my local machine everything is ok, but on the travis builds it seems to cant find that task.

Comment: Travis will build using the `.travis.yml`. Check what you are running in there.

Comment: i have a .travis.yml. everything runs great except trying to publish to google play using that gradle plugin. heres my travis --- https://gist.github.com/sirvon/c73a014e63f5c6f07558

Comment: can check out my setup... the whole problem is executing that task in travis correctly...currently travis is picking it up but locally everything is OK. running...../gradlew -S -i app:publishApkAPPRelease

Comment: I do not know how your project is setup but I dod not know what error you are seeing. I would simple use `gradlew :app:publish`.

Comment: So you ended up checking the keystore file in the repository. Right? Update: ah, they are encrypted. OK, gotcha!

Comment: A hacker could simply brute force the encrypted keystore from the public repo until he obtains a valid keystore file, then continue with brute forcing the keystore itself until he obtains the keystore alias and passwords. Isn't this a potentially bad idea?

Comment: Yeah, really not a fan of putting the keystore in the project for reasons mentioned by @PaulLammertsma. Seems dangerous.

Answer (score -3):

- When your application complete then after export it.
- At that time automatically generate key-store,SHA1 and MD5 keys which are used in play store or publicly.
- Now create your final APK file for play store and perfectly use publicly.

Comment: I am not sure if he even understood the question. The answer is irrelevant.